# How to test which validation failed in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, rspec, validation

I have a model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_length_of :name, :in => (2..5)
end
```

I want to test this validation:

```
it "should not allow too short name" do
  u = User.new(:name => "a")
  u.valid?
  u.should have(1).error_on(:name)
end
```

But then it does not test which kind of error was set on `name`. I want to know, if it was `too_short`, `too_long`, or maybe some other validation failed.

I can lookup the message text in errors array, like this:

```
u.errors[:name].should include(I18n.t("activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.too_short"))
```

But this will fail when I set `activerecord.errors.messages.too_short` in locale file instead of model-specific message.

So, is it possible to check which kind of error occured?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Rails [added an method to query for errors to ActiveModel in late 2011 and Rails v3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3369). Just check to see if the appropriate error has been [`#added?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-added-3F):

```
# An error added manually
record.errors.add :name, :blank
record.errors.added? :name, :blank # => true

# An error added after validation
record.email = 'taken@email.com'
record.valid? # => false
record.errors.added? :email, :taken, value: 'taken@email.com' # => true
```

Note that for validations that are parametrized (e.g. `:greater_than_or_equal_to`) you'll need to pass the value of the parameter too.

```
record.errors.add(:age, :greater_than_or_equal_to, count: 1)
record.errors.added?(:age, :greater_than_or_equal_to, count: 1)
```

Errors are identified by their i18n key. You can find the appropriate keys to check in the appropriate [Rails i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) file for any language under the [error section](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/46b1934e7cb2941341be11aa01b0cde86fc382f4/rails/locale/en.yml#L98).

Some other nifty questions you can ask `ActiveModel#Error` are [`#empty?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-empty-3F) and
[`#include?(attr)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-include-3F), as well as anything you can ask an [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html).

Comment: added? is a handy method. Combined with rspec syntax this could make it read very nicely. E.g. `expect(record.errors).to be_added :name, :blank`

Comment: Note, you need to pass options as the third parameter for some checks. e.g., `assert record.errors.added?(:slug, :too_short, count: 5)` where 5 is the required length.

Comment: Note that this solution only works for model validations.  Adding arbitrary errors cannot be checked with `#added?`  For example, `#added?` will return an error if checking for an error if `:name` or `:email` in the above example is not a model attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately `added?` is still doing error messages string comparison under the hood. This means we have to pass in interpolation value for it to work: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14067/files#r9781601 which is kinda annoying.

Answer (score 12):

I really don't like the idea of looking for translated error messages in Errors hash. After a conversation with a fellow Rubyists, I ended monkey patching Errors hash, so it saves the non-translated message first.

```
module ActiveModel
  class Errors
    def error_names
      @_error_names ||= { }
    end

    def add_with_save_names(attribute, message = nil, options = {})
      message ||= :invalid
      if message.is_a?(Proc)
        message = message.call
      end
      error_names[attribute] ||= []
      error_names[attribute] << message
      add_without_save_names(attribute, message, options)
    end

    alias_method_chain :add, :save_names
  end
end
```

Then you can test like this:

```
u = User.new(:name => "a")
u.valid?
u.errors.error_names[:name].should include(:too_short)
```

Comment: Rails should totally do this .. if it has validation types, the fact they don't persist through to the error object is weird and frustrating.

Comment: @MikeCampbell This answer is a bit outdated. Rails v3.2 provides this ability via `Error#added?`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119379/how-to-test-which-validation-failed-in-activerecord/#16800379) for more info.

Comment: @faraz, that is awesome. can't believe I couldn't find that. Thanks!

Comment: I would avoid any monkey patches.
Rails 5:
`person = Person.new
person.validate
person.errors.details[:name]
# => [{error: :blank}]`
Rails 4 backport: https://github.com/cowbell/active_model-errors_details

Answer (score 5):

I recommend checking out the gem [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) for handling these types of repetitive validation tests. It complements RSpec or Test::Unit so you can write concise specs such as:

```
describe User do
  it { should ensure_length_of(:name).is_at_least(2).is_at_most(5) }
end
```

Comment: Just looking at the code for this, it looks like it just looks for the message translation too. Looks nice though, and at least this way the code is being maintained as part of a dedicated library, not as part of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My goal was to test more complex validation scenario, so I did not want to use shoulda. I suppose that if shoulda works this way, there is no other way to check which validation failed.

Answer (score 5):

The approach I use:

```
it "should not allow too short name" do
  u = User.new(:name => "a")
  expect{u.save!}.to raise_exception(/Name is too short/)
end
```

I use a regex to match the exception message because there may be many validation messages in the exception message, but we want to ensure that it contains a specific snippet relating to the name being too short.

This approach does couple your assertions to your validation messages, so if you every modify your validation message you'll likely need to modify your specs as well. Overall though, this is a simple way to assert validations are doing their job.

Comment: But this saves the record if the test fails. Other side-effects could also occur. Why not use valid? to ensure you're just testing validation?