# How to determine ActiveModel::Errors validation type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

With the migration from Rails 2 to Rails 3 validation errors were moved from ActiveRecord::Error to ActiveModel::Errors.
In rails 2 the validation error had a type and a message (among other things) and you could check the type of the validation error by doing something like the following:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  e.record.errors.each do |attr, error|
    if error.type == :foo
      do_something
    end
  end
end
```

But with Rails 3 it seems everything but the invalid attribute and message has been lost.  As a result the only way to determine the type is to compare the error message:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  e.record.errors.each do |attr, error|
    if error == "foobar"
      do_something
    end
  end
end
```

Which is not at all ideal (eg. what if you have several validations which use the same message?).

**Question:**
Is there a better way in rails 3.0 to determine the type of validation error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test which validation failed in ActiveRecord?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119379/how-to-test-which-validation-failed-in-activerecord)

Answer (score 5):

Check for added? on ActiveModel::Errors:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L331

That allows you to do this:

```
record.errors.added?(:field, :error)
```

Comment: That would do the trick (although it too is only comparing the validation messages) but it has not been backported to 3.0 (which I didn't specifically mention, I'll update the question).

Comment: The bad thing about this that it relies on translated text message.

Answer (score 1):

I needed it not only for test purposes, but also for API. I've ended up with monkey patch:

```
module CoreExt
  module ActiveModel
    module Errors
      # When validation on model fails, ActiveModel sets only human readable
      # messages. This does not allow programmatically identify which
      # validation rule exactly was violated.
      #
      # This module patches {ActiveModel::Errors} to have +details+ property,
      # that keeps name of violated validators.
      #
      # @example
      #   customer.valid? # => false
      #   customer.errors.messages # => { email: ["must be present"] }
      #   customer.errors.details # => { email: { blank: ["must be present"] } }
      module Details
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        included do
          if instance_methods.include?(:details)
            fail("Can't monkey patch. ActiveModel::Errors already has method #details")
          end

          def details
            @__details ||= Hash.new do |attr_hash, attr_key|
              attr_hash[attr_key] = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
            end
          end

          def add_with_details(attribute, message = nil, options = {})
            error_type = message.is_a?(Symbol) ? message : :invalid
            normalized_message = normalize_message(attribute, message, options)
            details[attribute][error_type] << normalized_message

            add_without_details(attribute, message, options)
          end
          alias_method_chain :add, :details

          def clear_with_details
            details.clear
            clear_without_details
          end
          alias_method_chain :clear, :details
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# Apply monkey patches
::ActiveModel::Errors.send(:include, ::CoreExt::ActiveModel::Errors::Details)
```