# Rails ActiveRecord validation: Assert of errors.added? :inclusion unexpectedly fails with a false negative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, minitest

In my Rails (version 6.0.5.1) ActiveRecord model, I have an `inclusion` validation like this one:

```
validates :car_type, inclusion: ['coupe', 'sedan', 'convertible']
```

In the corresponding test file, I'm attempting to test that a validation error is raised when a value not in the list of valid values (like `'airplane'`) is assigned to this `car_type` attribute.

The following MiniTest assertions pass, as expected:

```
assert car.errors.invalid?
assert car.errors.include? :car_type
assert car.errors.added? :car_type, 'is not included in the list'
```

However, the following assertion fails with `Minitest::Assertion: Expected false to be truthy.`:

```
assert car.errors.added? :car_type, :inclusion
```

I would expect that this syntax *should* work, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800379/12484), and its linked [ActiveRecord i18n translation file](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/46b1934e7cb2941341be11aa01b0cde86fc382f4/rails/locale/en.yml#L110).

How can I get this last assertion to work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a change in behavior in Rails 5.2.2 where, when calling `.errors.added` ... `:inclusion` on an ActiveRecord object, a 3rd `value` parameter must be added specifying the invalid value.

This assertion passes, as expected:

```
assert car.errors.added? :car_type, :inclusion, value: 'airplane'
```

Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34652